# If $\int_0^1 f x^n dx=0, \forall n \in \mathbb{N} $, then $f\equiv 0.$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:[0,1]\to \mathbb{R}$ continuous, such that  $\forall n \in \mathbb{N},\int_0^1 f x^n dx=0$, show that $f\equiv 0$.

I think I should use Stone-Weierstrass Theorem and the Bernstein Polynomials, but I failed in my attempt of using, because the coefficients change at each power you choose. Is there any other way to do it, or someone that could help me with this method?

Comment: You do not need that $f$ is continuous. With Stone-Weierstrass, you can approximate any continuous functions by polynomials, and the continuous functions lie dense in the $L^1$-functions, which $f$ is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prove that $f^2$ is $0$ on the interval, by approximating $f$ by polynomials.

You should add the assumption of $f$ being continuous.

Answer (score 3):

Another approach: Since $\{x^m\}_{m=0} ^\infty $ is a spanning set of $L_2[a,b]$  and we know $f \perp x^m$ for all $m$ then $f \perp \mathrm{span}\{x^m\}_{m=0}^ \infty $.

Now since $f$ is perpendicular to a dense subset of $L_2[0,1]$ it must be that $f=0$ almost everywhere.